# ‘sockaddr_in6_t’ undeclared error even after inclusing the header files

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I have following simple piece of code, which is a part of ipv6 handling module in a big project.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
  sockaddr_in6_t* pSadrIn6 = (sockaddr_in6_t*) malloc(sizeof sockaddr_in6_t);
  return 0;
}
```

It gives me following not error:

```
error: ‘sockaddr_in6_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Is there any special library installation or linking that I need to access the library?

Comment: Try using `struct sockaddr_in6*` instead of `sockaddr_in6_t*` to see if you're just missing the `typedef`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you copied this code from the [Linux IPv6 HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/chapter-section-using-api.html) but didn't copy the additional typedefs:

```
/*
** Type definitions (for convenience).
*/
typedef enum { false = 0, true } boolean;
typedef struct sockaddr_in       sockaddr_in_t;
typedef struct sockaddr_in6      sockaddr_in6_t;
```

Personally I would just use the types as they are (instead of extra `typedefs` to avoid typing `struct`), but whatever